# Homeland season 8 ep.12, What was wrong with "on my way in" message?

Tags: homeland

In ep. 12 of 8th season, while Saul had been captured, Wellington was waiting for him to attend a meeting with journalists. Wellington had called Saul but no one answered.
At that moment, guys who kept Saul wrote a message from his phone: "Got your message. On my way in" addressed to Wellington, and somehow, he understood that something is wrong, emphasizing that the matter was in "in".
So, could one explain whats wrong with that message? I'm not a native speaker and thats seems ok to me. May it be connected to the place of meeting Saul was to attend?

Comment: AFAIR I took it as being not so much about the correctness of the message, but it being a remarkable thing for Saul to write, as he would never phrase it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You misunderstood](https://tvline.com/2020/04/26/homeland-recap-series-finale-season-8-episode-12/):

> Back in D.C, Saul’s captors arouse suspicion when they text Wellington from Saul’s phone that he’s “on his way in”… **but his meeting with Wellington isn’t at the office.**

Comment: Yes, tnx, I've get it) what i haven't is: the message was "on my way in". It could be a way in office, in cafe, in whatever else or I'm wrong?

Comment: "On my way in", in a work context, means 'to the workplace'. In English you wouldn't say "I'm on my way in" if you were meeting at a cafe, even if it was for a work meeting. *Maybe* if you were starting your journey in a different town to where your destination was; but that doesn't apply here